# How do I count up certain words (not just one word) in a string and then output different code if there are different amounts of words?

Tags: python, if-statement, counter

Sorry for lengthy question, I didn't know how to word it specifically without it being marked as a duplicate. Anyway, I am trying to count up a set of keywords that a user has inputted which is written into a text file. Here is the code:

```
import os
def keyword_searcher():
user_query = input("Enter your problem:\n")
with open("user_query.txt", "a+") as query:
    query.write(user_query.lower())
    query.seek(0)
    for line in query:
        for word in line.split():
            if word in ("backlight", "display", "cracked", "touchscreen"):
                with open("Solutions1.txt", "r") as f:
                    solution_one  = f.read()
                    print ("Keyword for screen problem found:\n")
                    print (solution_one)
            elif word in ("battery", "charger", "usb", "charge"):
                with open("Solutions2.txt", "r") as f_two:
                    solution_two = f_two.read()
                    print ("Keyword for battery problem found:\n")
                    print(solution_two)
            elif word in ("virus", "hacked", "infected", "antivirus"):
                with open("Solutions3.txt", "r") as f_three:
                    solution_three = f_three.read()
                    print ("Keyword for virus problem found:\n")
                    print (solution_three)
            else:
                pass
keyword_searcher()
os.remove("user_query.txt")
```

My problem is, when the user inputs more than one of any keywords, it outputs the code that amount of times, when I only want it once. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for word in line.split():
    if word in ("backlight", "display", "cracked", "touchscreen"):
       ...
```

means that you'll check one word per iteration of the loop, so if more than one word matches, you get duplicates. To do it only when at least one of the words is present in the list, use `set`s:

```
for line in query:
    words = set(line.split())
    if words & {"backlight", "display", "cracked", "touchscreen"}:
        ...
```

Alternatively, you could do something like

```
for line in query:
    words = line.split()
    if any(word in ("backlight", "display", "cracked", "touchscreen") for word in words):
        ...
```

which may be easier to read but would be slower.

Comment: Thank you so much! This works like a charm now, and I now understand what `&` and `set()` do!

Answer (score 1):

You can really slim this program down. There is no need to write the user input to a file and remove it at the end, just store it as a variable. You should check every statement with an `if` statement to ensure it checks each one. Also, the `else: pass` is redundant. Hopefully this helps you out, good luck with your program:

```
list_one = ["backlight", "display", "cracked", "touchscreen"]
list_two = ["battery", "charger", "usb", "charge"]
list_three = ["virus", "hacked", "infected", "antivirus"]

user_query = input("Enter your problem:\n").split()

if any(word in list_one for word in user_query):
    with open("Solutions1.txt") as f:
        solution_one  = f.read()
        print("Keyword for screen problem found:\n")
        print(solution_one)

if any(word in list_two for word in user_query):
    with open("Solutions2.txt") as f_two:
        solution_two = f_two.read()
        print("Keyword for battery problem found:\n")
        print(solution_two)

if any(word in list_three for word in user_query):
    with open("Solutions3.txt") as f_three:
        solution_three = f_three.read()
        print("Keyword for virus problem found:\n")
        print(solution_three)
```

Comment: Thank you for this but the program description (this is for school) and the teacher insists on using text files (which I see no point in because, as you say, it can be slimmed down without them). Nevertheless, this is a helpful answer, thanks.